# how to open different urls at the same time by using python selenium?

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

is this possible to open 50 different urls at the same time using selenium with python?
is this possible using threading?

If so, how would I go about doing this?

If not, then what would be a good method to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below to open 50 URLs *one by one in new tab*:

```
urls = ["http://first.com", "http://second.com", ...]

for url in urls:
    driver.execute_script('window.open("%s")' % url)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use celery (Distributed Task Queue) to open all these urls.

or you can use async and await with aiohttp on python >= 3.5 , which runs a single thread on a single process but concurrently(utilises the wait time on urls for fetching other urls)
here is the code sample for the same. Loop takes care of scheduling these concurrent tasks.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.5
import asyncio
from aiohttp import ClientSession

async def hello(url):
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as response:
           response = await response.read()
           print(response)

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

loop.run_until_complete(hello("http://httpbin.org/headers"))
```

Answer (score 0):

well, open 50 urls at the same time seems unreasonable and will require a  LOT of processing, but, is possible. However i would recommend you to use a form of iteration opening one url at a time. 50 times.

```
list = ['list of urls here','2nd url'...]
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
for i in list:
  moving = driver.get(i)
  ...#rest of your code
driver.quit()
```

but... you can make one `driver.get('url')` for each url you want... using different drivers. Or tabs. But it will require a lot of processing.